# When a <td> in a table has some text in it, auto check(tick) a check box which is outside of the table

Tags: checkbox, html-table

I want check box to auto-check when there's text in `<td>` of table:
[image]

Comment: I tried simply with javascript; then i tried with 'isset' of php, but still not getting it. Could you please help? @Brian Keller-Heikkila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to check the `innerHTML` of the `td` and if that is empty `""` then you can change the `checked` attribute of checkbox to `true`

Example:

```
<table>
   <td id='abcd'>Put some content here and try and try without any content</td>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk">

<script>
  var td = document.getElementById("abcd");
  var chk = document.getElementById("chk");
  if(td.innerHTML.trim()!=""){
    chk.checked = true; 
  }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/3p6ucfnm/

Comment: Sir is that <script> code javascript or jquery?
Because when I'm trying it in jsfiddle it's working, but when i try in my browser with sublime texteditor, it's not working sir. @Tintu C Raju

Comment: its pure javascript. And i have tried it in my browser also. Simply copy the code into an html file and try. also check your console for errors..

Comment: @ Tintu C Raju Thankyou so much sir; was trying this for the last 2 days. Thankyou very very much, and here's an upvote!